# How to get post views with the help of Facbook API Graf

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get post statistics on Facebook. I need to get the number of likes, dislikes, veiws and comment. I have already found the way to get post information: [https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{page_name}?fields=name,posts&access_token=____](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7Bpage_name%7D?fields=name,posts&access_token=____)_
But when I'm trying to get likes and comments, I get nothing: [https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{page_name}?fields=name,posts{reactions,comments}&access_token=](https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/%7Bpage_name%7D?fields=name,posts%7Breactions,comments%7D&access_token=)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not getting any specific reactions and comments, because you lack the right to access those. (They contain user data, and user data is only available if the individual user gave your app permission.)

If you only need the overall count, then ask for the `summary`:

```
?fields=name,posts{reactions.summary(1),comments.summary(1)}
```

Comment: thank you! there is one more thing i can't anderstand. how can i give access to the app if both the app and the page are mine?

Comment: Access to what, exactly? Individual reactions/comments, that contain user data? As I said, I don't think you can any more; unless the user who made them was also a user of your app. (When you leave a comment yourself with your own user account, do you see that?)